# Does Cordova 2.0.0 work for iOS 6.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios6, cordova

My PhoneGap App(Cordova 2.0.0) works fine on iOS 5.1, but when I update iOS to 6.0, there seems some issues. My question is: 
1. Is cordova 2.0.0 compatible with iOS 6.0?
2. Is cordova 2.0.0 compatible with JQuery-mobile 1.1.0 (JQuery 1.7.2)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention what 'issues' there seems to be. Knowing that would help to troubleshooting what is going on.

Per http://phonegap.com/download, Phonegap 2 was released in **July of 2012**. iOS 6 was released in **September of 2012**.

**PhoneGap 2.1** was released shortly thereafter, with a version **2.2** available already. According to the 2.1 announcment, [iOS 6 support was introduced](http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/09/21/phonegap-210/). Chances are there were some small issues with compatibility and newer APIs, but without knowing what you are seeing, it's all guess work.

You may want to upgrade.

Comment: If you are using iOS6 then you will want to upgrade to PhoneGap 2.2.0.